# Value of 1 array equals the value of another in Android

Tags: android, arrays

I have two arrays :

```
String []myExpressions = {"20+10","50+50","25+25","10+15"};
String []answers = {"30#","100#","50#","25#"};
```

When the user clicks the generate button it generates an expression from the array `myExpressions` and displays it in text-field. Then I require the user to enter the answer using the buttons provided. The answer is displayed in a EditText. When the user enters an answer they should enter a #(like a submit button) and if is the correct answer it should display correct in a text-field. So if the position in the expression array is 1, the correct answer is in the answer array in the same position. How would i check if they are in the same position?

For example: `myExpressions[1]` correct answer to this is `answers[1]`.

Here is my code:

```
package com.gamesup.braingame;

import java.util.Random;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Easy extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

EditText display;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.easy);

    display = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.displayText);
    display.setText("?");

    final String []myExpressions = {"20+10","50+50","25+25","10+15"};
    final String []answers = {"30#","100#","50#","25#"};

    final TextView displayExpression = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.expression);
    Button generate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.random_gen);

    generate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Random ranGenerate = new Random ();
            int random = ranGenerate.nextInt(4) ;
            displayExpression.setText(myExpressions[random]);
        }
    });

}

static boolean isEmpty = true;

public void num_Clicked(View v){
    Button btn = (Button) findViewById(v.getId());
    //getting the button object and using a view to get the id of the buttons

     if (v.getId()== R.id.del_button){
            String s = display.getText().toString();
            s = s.substring(0, s.length() - 1);
            display.setText(s);
            return;
     }


    if(isEmpty){
        display.setText(btn.getText());
        isEmpty = false;
    }
    else{
        display.append(btn.getText().toString()); 
        // storing the existing number into editText and current text is set 
        //to current button value
        //display.setText(number+btn.getText().toString());
        //the total in the editText
    }

    if (v.getId()== R.id.hash_button){
        String userAns = display.getText().toString();



    }

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}


 }
```

Comment: Clearly state what is not working or what is wrong ?

Comment: how would i get myExpressions array to equal answers array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For starters arrays in Java Begin at Index 0 so therefore , to compare the first items of the Array you should be using something like this to check if things are equal:

```
EditText myAnswer = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.myAnswer);

String answer = myAnswer.getText().toString();

// Notice my loop starts at 0 because the first index of an array is 0
for(int i = 0 ; i < answers.length; i++)
{   
  if(answers[i].equals(answer))
  {
     // Congratulate the User for getting it Right


  }
}
```

It seems as though you have a little bit of a shaky logic. IMHO you should be using a multidimensional Array.

With a multidimensional Array you can essentially set up keys and values.

This is how I think your application should be configures

```
 // This Array says , I am an array that holds arrays
 String [][] multiArray = {{"4 + 5", "9"},     
                            {"20 * 3","60"},
                            {"99 - 9","90"}};  

 // Fetch your random question, since we know our questions are the first item in out Array we can use the index [x][0] depending on the index you pull from
 String question = multiArray[0][0];

 // To do this randomly
 Random ranGenerate = new Random ();
 int random = ranGenerate.nextInt(4) ;
 String question = multiArray[random][0];

 // Get the Answer from yout EditText
 String answer =  myAnswer.getText().toString();

 // Using a for loop iterate on the base index
 for(int i = 0; i < multiArray.length ; i++)
 {
      // if the answer is in position 1 of Array [i] 
      if(answer.equals(mutliArray[i][1])
      {
        // We have found the answer, Congratulate the User 

      }else{
        // Tell them how bad they are since they can't solve simple equations!
        // ....joking obviously we would be nice and let them know its not the answer
      }

 }
```

Comment: Yeah, i think this is something i was after. I haven't really used multidimensional Array. Could you edit that in the code i gave because it is saying i need to define locally in the for loop. I have tried in the onClick method and the onCreate method. I'm also not sure where i would have to add this code :/

Comment: EDIT: It works, I didn't realise multiArray was not correctly spelled in the for loop. Thank You.

Comment: No problem, i enjoy helping! Keep in mind though about the indexes, you may be seeing something you don't expect just remember that if you choose multiArray[x][0] you will be getting the first element(your question) in the array of elements, at index x of the array where x can be any number less than the array length etc.

Answer (score 0):

In this line

```
int random = ranGenerate.nextInt(4) ;
```

why don't you make `random` an instance variable inside your class? This way you would preserve the index, and you would know which index to use to compare the answer.